# significant mean difference over time?

Tags: mean

I need help. I am looking at two data sets that come from two surveys asked of the same group with the same population over a year apart. Year one, the group was asked to rate 15 statements on a scale of 1-5 and year two the group was asked to rate the same statements on the same scale. I want to know if there is a way to figure out at what point is the score in year two significantly different from the score in year 1. (eg. if year 1 score was 3.7 and year 2 score was 3.9, is the .2 difference significantly different?)

I understand I can use the t-test to look at the mean of each question and compare it to the year before. But I want to know at what point overall, is it .1, .2, .3? I understand the population has a large effect on the answer, so if I asked another group with a higher population over two years, what will that number be for them?

Comment: do you have monthly data or daily data or what?

Comment: Yearly. The survey is conducted once every year.

Comment: You want to do power analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a linear mixed model for this. This is about statistical significance, which is estimated / inferred from the sample, so we cannot give you a fixed number. If you want more details you will have to provide some data.

Comment: Here is an example from 2017:

Comment: Here is an example from 2017:
Overall, I am very satisfied as an employee of this organization.
5
4
4
5
5
4
5
5
5
5
2
4
4

From 2018: 
Overall, I am very satisfied as an employee of this organization.
3
5
5
5
5
4
3
5
4
5
3
4
4

This is one question, I have 14 more like these. I want to put the scores on a table with year one and year two and delta and highlight all the delta's that are statistically significant. At what point would I highlight the delta? .2, .3, .4, etc.

Comment: FYI, this is the whole population, 100% response rate and not a sample.

Comment: @Yahya Can you please edit your question with this new information? Also, if you could add an additional year that would be even better. Some clarifications, are these all from the same people every year? Are they in the right order? So the first measurement in year 1 is for the same individual for measurement 1 in year 2? Also, are you trying to compare each year with the previous year, too see if there are differences for each year? Delta for you would be the difference year 2 - year 1?

Comment: Almost the same people, not in the right order. you are correct in that delta would be year 2 - year 1.

Comment: @Yahya Wait, I missed the part about this being data for the whole population, not a sample. If that is true, then there is no statistics to be done. There are no estimates or p-values.